# I can't access MySQL once I've bound it to an external IP

Tags: mysql, database, bind, ip-address, remote-access

I have installed MySQL on a public facing server, and set up tables etc. I then figured out I need to enable remote access so I can pass data to it. I found this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

I followed this but when I try and access the MySQL Database Prompt, after the new IP address is in effect, it just closes once I have entered the password. So I can't view tables and create new ones whilst I'm on the server itself.

Is there a special way I have to log in now I've changed the bind IP address away from localhost?

Thanks

Comment: I hope you have network security in place? Did you setup SSL communication? Generally speaking you dont expose your database server directly to the internet without serious network security around it.

Comment: We have sufficient security. We're trying to connect reporting software (Jreport) to the SQL database to retrieve results and create a report

Comment: Can you telnet to the public ip and port? i.e. telnet www.thisisthedb.com 3306?